# Catching a browser address before it gets referred to a proxy

Tags: c++, windows, http, bho

I’m writing a BHO (Browser Helper Object) that catches the address the user enters checks it and the depending on the result performs a cretin operation.

The BHO hooks into the browser events and then i catch the DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2 event and do my stuff.

My problem is that our users all have a internal proxy server that will sometimes block sites when this happens the address i get in the DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2 event is the address the proxy returned, when the address i really need is the one the user typed in.

**Anyone know how I can catch the address before I’m referred to the proxy?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this.
I was getting the URL from the browser object so what I was actually getting was the page displayed ans since the proxy message was a redirect it was never displayed so I never saw it.

I have now switched to getting the URL from the DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2 parameters:

```
LPTSTR CBhoApp::varToStr(VARIANT var)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    if(var.vt == VT_BSTR)
    {
        LPTSTR psz = new TCHAR[SysStringLen(var.bstrVal)];
        lstrcpy(psz, OLE2T(var.bstrVal));
        return psz;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
STDMETHODIMP CBhoApp::Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *pDispParams, VARIANT *pvarResult, EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr)
{

    BSTR bstrUrlName;
    LPTSTR psz;
    if(dispidMember == DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2)
    {
        //This is the parameter for the URL.
        VARIANT* tmp = pDispParams->rgvarg[5].pvarVal;
        psz = varToStr(*tmp);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```